# Dataflow GroupByKey transform splits input rows

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I run a data flow job to read data from files stored in GCS, each record has an "event type", my goal is to split the data per "event type" and write each output to a bq table, now I'm using a filter to do this, however I'd like to try GroupByKey transform which hopefully can make the process dynamic as new Event Types will flow in over time which can't be predicted at the development time. So now my challenge is, I don't know if its possible to construct a WRITE transform per each KEY(the key from output GroupByKey)?  It would be ideal if its doable, or any other ways can achieve this, any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a transform for each value of event type; you just need to write a transform that can handle all values for event type.

A GroupByKey will produce a PCollection<KV<EventType, Iterable<ValueType>>. So each record of this PCollection is a key value pair. The key is an EventType and the value is an iterable of values with this key type. You can then apply a transform which converts each of these keys into a TableRow representing the row you want to create in BigQuery. You can do this by defining a:

```
ParDo<KV<EventType, Iterable<ValueType>>, TableRow>
```

For example, if your EventType is a string and your ValueType is a string then you might emit a row with two columns for each key value pair. The first column might just be a string corresponding to the EventType and the  second column could be a comma separated list of the values.

Comment: this will work when all the keys and their corresponding values go to one target table, however my case is slightly different, I need to output each key's values to one table, i.e,: one target table per key, meaning I will need to be able to determine target table name per each key at run time, does this make sense?

Comment: That makes sense; but unfortunately there's no way to dynamically set the table at runtime. If you wanted to you could write a ParDo that would use the BigQuery API to write each record to the table of your choice. In this case the table could be a function of the key. However, if you use this approach you will need to handle deduping and other administrative tasks yourself.